# Input type=''button'' not working in IE 11

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

My form input type="button" /form isn't working IE 11. The point of the button is to go back 1 page in history. 
It is working in Google Chrome.
I've read on the internet that IE has some issues implementing HTML5, but I haven't managed to find a solution.

Not only the JS part of the button isn't working, because the hover in IE11 isn't showing as well.

The code in Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Luj5sqh7/3/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Stabiliteit Houtribdijk</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
</style>

<div class="header">

  <div class="headerleft">
    <form>
      <input type="button" class="button" value="Terug"     onclick="history.go(-1);return true;">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="headerright">
    <H4>Stabiliteit dijk animatie </H4>
  </div>
  <!--  <div class="headerlogo">
    <img src="images/Rhdhvlogo.jpg" id="rhdhvlogo"/>
</div>-->
</div>

</head>
<body>

<video onclick="this.paused?this.play():this.pause()" class="videocenter" controls>
  <source src="movie/STABILITEITTotaal.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie/STABILITEITTotaal.ogg" type="video/ogg"> Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: your whole markup is wrong.. if this is what you have actually written

Answer (score 0):

the probleme is not the type of input I think this is your

```
z-index: -1;
```

on your body